# LEFT OUTER JOIN not showing rows where missing on the RIGHT side of JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle11g, left-join

I'm building up a query to return for a given employee, all 'tests' that are need for that persons role, where the person has either not taken the test, or the test has expired.

The first part, listing all the tests for the employees role is as follows:

```
SELECT e.EMP_NO, e.POS_CODE, p.PROPERTY_CODE, p.PROPERTY_VALUE
FROM COMPANY_PERS_ASSIGN e
INNER JOIN COMPANY_POS_PROPERTY_ALL p ON p.POS_CODE = e.POS_CODE
WHERE e.EMP_NO = '3615';
```

So far so good... for this example, it lists 4 tests required for this persons role.

Next, I need to join it to the view that shows which tests an employee has taken:

```
SELECT e.EMP_NO, e.POS_CODE, p.PROPERTY_CODE, p.PROPERTY_VALUE, ep.PROPERTY_CODE, ep.PROPERTY_VALUE
FROM COMPANY_PERS_ASSIGN e
INNER JOIN COMPANY_POS_PROPERTY_ALL p ON p.POS_CODE = e.POS_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY_EMPLOYEE_PROPERTY_ALL ep ON ep.PROPERTY_VALUE = p.PROPERTY_VALUE
WHERE e.EMP_NO = '3615';
```

With a LEFT OUTER JOIN, I would expect it to return all the rows from the previous query, with any matching information from the view we have just added in.

If the tests for this role were A/B/C/D, and if this employee had done test A once, and test D 3 times, I would have expected the following output:

```
3615 POS1 A A A A
3615 POS1 B B
3615 POS1 C C
3615 POS1 D D D D
3615 POS1 D D D D
3615 POS1 D D D D
```

But instead I get:

```
3615 POS1 A A A A
3615 POS1 D D D D
3615 POS1 D D D D
3615 POS1 D D D D
```

I'm more familiar with T-SQL than PL/SQL but as far as I can tell, I should have taken the right approach, but clearly something isn't right.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**
I realised an error in my logic - in my original code sample, I JOINed to the COMPANY_EMPLOYEE_PROPERTY_ALL table, linking via PROPERTY_VALUE (i.e. the test) but didn't take any account of the employee.

To address this (and to try something different), I introduced a sub-query:

```
SELECT e.EMP_NO, e.POS_CODE, p.PROPERTY_VALUE, p.value_description, ep.PROPERTY_VALUE, ep.value_description, ep.VALID_TO
FROM COMPANY_PERS_ASSIGN e
INNER JOIN COMPANY_POS_PROPERTY_ALL p ON p.POS_CODE = e.POS_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (Select ep.PROPERTY_VALUE, ep.VALID_TO, ep.value_description
    FROM COMPANY_PERS_ASSIGN e
    INNER JOIN COMPANY_EMPLOYEE_PROPERTY_ALL ep ON ep.EMP_NO = e.EMP_NO
    WHERE e.EMP_NO = '3615') ep on ep.PROPERTY_VALUE = p.PROPERTY_VALUE
WHERE e.EMP_NO = '3615'
AND (to_char(ep.VALID_TO) <= '17-APR-12' OR ep.VALID_To IS NULL);
```

This solution works.

However, given the gotcha that I spotted, how can I re-jig the original approach? Or should I just stick with this solution. I'm at the 'working' stage, but I'm always looking for further elegance (and an opportunity to learn).

Comment: Your code seems fine. The only reason I can imagine that would remove rows from left side is a filter on right side. Is e.EMP_NO the only filter in q query?

Comment: Can you add scripts to create your tables and populate them in such a way that it'll reproduce your situation ?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović - Once I have this SQL working I may add additional filters, but as it stands we only look at e.EMP_NO in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @A.B.Cade - I'll knock up some DDL/DML shortly.

Comment: Besides the "joins" issue, why do you do `to_char(ep.VALID_TO) <= '17-APR-12'` ? is ep.VALID_TO a date ? if it is, then you need to compare it to another date, ie `ep.VALID_TO <= to_date('20120417', 'yyyymmdd')`

Comment: It's hard to tell without a test case, but did you try to add to your original query (in the left outer join criteria) `... ON ep.PROPERTY_VALUE = p.PROPERTY_VALUE AND ep.EMP_NO = e.EMP_NO ...`

Comment: @A.B.Cade - re: Dates - I actually got the suggestion from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Select-Query/Datacolumncompare.htm. I'm less familiar with Oracle, so I searched for the solution online. But I understand your suggested alternative - makes sense.

Comment: @A.B.Cade re: Join Criteria - No, I went straight from the original attempt to the sub-query version. During that process, I realised my mistake. However, I've just modified the the original SQL and I wouldn't surprise either of us that it works. Once the DB has optimised the queries, there will likely be little or no difference in performance, however, I prefer the (modified) original. Seeing as it is the direct answer to my original question, perhaps you could **post it as an answer**, to neatly close this question off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add to your left outer join criteria a condition related to `EMP_NO`:

```
SELECT e.EMP_NO, e.POS_CODE, p.PROPERTY_CODE, p.PROPERTY_VALUE, ep.PROPERTY_CODE, ep.PROPERTY_VALUE
FROM COMPANY_PERS_ASSIGN e
INNER JOIN COMPANY_POS_PROPERTY_ALL p ON p.POS_CODE = e.POS_CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY_EMPLOYEE_PROPERTY_ALL ep ON ep.PROPERTY_VALUE = p.PROPERTY_VALUE
                                                AND ep.EMP_NO = e.EMP_NO
WHERE e.EMP_NO = '3615'
-- AND (ep.VALID_TO <= to_date('20120417', 'yyyymmdd') OR ep.VALID_To IS NULL)
```

Comment: I'm not well-versed in Oracle, does it treat `NULL` as less than `to_date('20120417', 'yyyymmdd')`?  If not, you'd be better off moving the `ep.VALID_TO <= to_date('20120417', 'yyyymmdd')` into the LEFT OUTER JOIN condition.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... should have been with the `OR ep.VALID_To IS NULL`, but since I'm not sure how you want to use it, I'll just remove it